# Better Sharepoint development model- App model or Sharepoint Framework?

Tags: sharepoint-online

My organization has decided to move to Sharepoint online so we need to re-create our custom traditional webparts with a technology that is compatible with SP online. I can either go with Add-in model or Sharepoint framework but I am not able to decide on which model I should put more efforts. Which is better?

Answer (score 6):

If you are building webparts in SharePoint Online, then SharePoint Framework is the way to go. SharePoint framework solves one of the main problem (among many other problems) with Add-in webparts which is webparts are loaded in iframe, which causes poor loading experience.

**Why you should NOT use Add-in model for webparts?**

> The current option for solutions that run in NoScript sites is the
>   add-in/app-part model. This implementation creates an _iFrame _where
>   the actual experiences lives and executes. The main strength here is
>   that since it is external to the system and has no access to the
>   current DOM/connection, it is easier to trust and deploy for
>   information workers. They can be installed on NoScript sites by end
>   users.
>
> There are a couple of downsides though. First, they run in an iFrame,
>   which has a collection of issues associated with them. They are slower
>   than the script editor web part, as it winds up being a completely new
>   request to another page. This page has to go through authentication
>   and authorization, make its own calls to get SharePoint data, load
>   various JavaScript libraries and more. Whereas a script editor might
>   typically take, for example, 100ms to load and render while an
>   app-part might take upwards of 2 seconds or more. Additionally, the
>   _iFrame _ boundary makes it more difficult to create responsive designs, inherit CSS and theming information, etc. However, it does
>   have a heightened sense of security, which can be useful from the
>   developers perspective (my page is inaccessible by other controls on
>   the page) and from the end users perspective (the control has no
>   access to my connection to Office 365).
>
> Additionally, neither of these solutions work for the product team
>   itself. The product team historically created web parts as full trust
>   C# assemblies that were installed on the cloud servers. However, the
>   majority of our current development work is almost entirely JavaScript
>   running in a browser making REST API calls to the SharePoint and
>   Office 365 back end workloads. C# assemblies don’t work in this world,
>   so we also needed an updated development model.

**Why should SPFx be used?**

> - It runs in the context of the current user and connection in the    browser. No iFrames.
> - The controls are rendered in the normal page DOM. The controls are responsive and accessible by nature.
> - There is a  life cycle that the developer is involved in. It’s not just render, but load, _serialize _and deserialize, configuration
>     changes, etc.
> - It is framework agnostic – You can use any browser framework that you    like – React, Handlebars, knockout, angular – take your pick.
> - The tool chain is based on common open source client development tools    like npm, TypeScript, yeoman, webpack, gulp, etc.
> - Performance is key.
> - SPFx client-side solutions that are approved by the tenant    administrators (or their delegates) can be used by end users on all
>     sites – even self service created sites like teams, groups, personal, 
>     etc.
> - Can be deployed in both classic web part and publishing pages as    well as the modern pages.

Source for above excerpt is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

You can read more about design considerations for building your webpart [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/design-considerations-for-web-parts)